# Android - How to access emulator screenshot via emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-screen

My app allows the user to take a screenshot which it then sends to the server.

On a real device, the screenshots are saved at `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/` so that is fine.

But on the emulator, when I click the **Take screenshot** button (which is located in the panel beside the emulator), the screenshot is saved to my computer, but I can't find it anywhere in the emulator's file system - the `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/` directory exists, but the `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/` sub-directory does not.

Is there any way I can access the screenshot image on the emulator, or is there another way of taking the screenshot?

Comment: I think most of the answers aren't getting your question. You are looking for a way to save the screenshot inside the `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots` of the emulator itself right? Can't you use the `power + volume down` combination on the emulator? does it work?

Comment: Thanks, Daniele - but how how I click both buttons at the same time?

Comment: using hotkeys maybe? I acutally don't know for sure

Comment: Have just tried hotkeys, but no joy. I clicked the three dots (Extended controls) on the emulator panel, then selected **Help** and it shows all the keyboards shortcuts, but `ctrl+S` to take a screenshot works just like the aforementioned **Take screenshot** button. When I do `ctrl+P` (Power button) with `ctrl+-` (Volume down), it just powers off... :-/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Emulate Volume Down + Power event to trigger Android's screenshot, then screenshot pictures will be stored at emulator's `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots`.

Here is the script. Run `adb shell`, then copy the code below and run, you should see the emulator start taking a screenshot.

```
cat > /data/local/tmp/screenshot.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
echo 'volume key: down'
sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 114 1
echo 'power key: down'
sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 116 1
sendevent /dev/input/event1 0 0 0
sleep 1
echo 'volume key: up'
sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 114 0
echo 'power key: up'
sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 116 0
sendevent /dev/input/event1 0 0 0
EOF
sh /data/local/tmp/screenshot.sh
```

NOTE: My emulator's input device is "/dev/input/event1", this may be different for other devices. You can get the device info by running `adb shell getevent` command, then press the emulator's key, the output will be something like this(My Volume Down key, these are hex numbers, so 0x0072 is 114d):

```
/dev/input/event1: 0001 0072 00000001
/dev/input/event1: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0001 0072 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0000 0000 00000000
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not familiar with adb, but I've not added it to my path and can run `adb shell` - which shows **generic_x86:/**. From this point, I'm not sure how to paste your code in. *Ctrl+C* doesn't work and if I try typing your code in line by line, nothing seems to happen.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering If you are using Windows, click the top left icon ->edit->paste; If you are using linux, right click to show context menu -> paste.

Comment: You're a star! :-) Thanks very much - works a treat!

Comment: Under Android 9 I had to run the last command as root, but it worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 8):

It **will save in your PC** . You can also specify the location of screenshots from the **emulator settings**.

Please see the following image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Pretty old question, but you can use power menu:
Press and hold Power button
[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much simpler and effective way of getting a screenshot on the device itself.

Comment: It's a great and easy way to simulate the screenshot on newer emulators. However for older emulators like API 21, had to use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44497243/2452764

Answer (score 4):

It will save in your **device** (PC), you can see the location from the emulator setting, click on **more icon** from right side of your emulator, and then click on **setting**

[image: screen shot location]

Comment: Thanks, but the **Screenshot save location** is the file path for my computer, not for the emulator(?)

Answer (score 0):

Use `adb screencap` command to your emulated device this should store the screen capture on the device itself allowing you to test your application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to

> Emulator settings > Settings > General > Screenshot save location >
> '***your file path***'

2. then select your desire location to save your screenshot.
   to find your taken screenshot you have to go your ***your file path*** which found by step 1.

hope its work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can prevent the user from taking a screenshot and capturing the screen(Kotlin):

```
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // ...
    window.setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Not answer of asked question

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33282659)